# Generate output of query for 2 tables which don't have relations

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:
Sessions with column StartDate, UserID
and
User with columns FullName,UPN,ID

There are many other columns in both tables but any of them has relations with each other.

Can you help me to write a query:

Select StartDate from Sessions where startdate is greater than 1 month and lower than current date, FullName,UPN from User.

I was trying with this query but without success:

```
SELECT StartDate  
FROM Session  
WHERE ((startdate >= '20180306') AND (startdate <= '20180406')) 
UNION 
SELECT FullName, Upn 
FROM User
```

Is there any method how to do that? Should I use a keys from different tables?

Comment: The two SELECTs must return same number of columns, and have matching data types. And do UNION ALL.

Comment: Can I change a datetime type to string which will be same like FullName ? + take out UPN so number of cullumns will be same for both SELECTs ?

Comment: Yes, you can cast as character to get matching data types. (And select NULL to get same number of columns.)

Comment: I would look very closely at the Sessions table. Are you sure there's not a Cust ID or equivalent of 'who' signed into the session?

Comment: You can take a look below what columns are in both tables.

Comment: UserId is your join column.   You should add the information in the comments to your post

Comment: As the `Sessions` table has a `UserID` it is obviously related to the `User` table. So "for 2 tables which don't have relations" is plain wrong. Then what is "where startdate is greater than 1 month" supposed to mean? How can a date be greater than a number of months? And please: tag the request with the DBMS you are using, show sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to reflect information in comments

```
select 
    a.startdate,
    b.fullname,
    b.upn
from
    sessions a
    inner user b on a.UserId = b.id
where
    startdate between dateadd(month,-1,getdate()) and getdate()
```

Comment: This is the content of both TABLES:

Comment: SESSION Table

SessionKey (PK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
Startdate(datetime, null)
LogOnDuration(int, null)
EndDate(datetime, null)
ExitCode(int, null)
FailureDate(datetime, null)
ConnectionState(int, null)
ConnectionStateChangeDate(datetime, not null)
LifecycleState(int, null)
CurrentConnectionID(FK, bigint, null)
UserID(FK, bigint, null)
MachineID(FK, uniqueidentifier, null)
SessionType(int, not null)
IsAnonymous(bit, not null)
CreatedDate(datetime, not null)
ModifiedDate(datetie, not null)
FailureID(FK, bigint, null)
SessionIdelTime(datetime, null)

Comment: USERS Table

Id(PK, bigint, not null)
Sid(nvarchar(255), not null)
Upn(nvarchar(255), not null)
UserName(nvarchar(255), not null)
FullName(nvarchar(255), not null)
Domain(nvarchar(255), not null)
CreatedDate(datetime, not null)
ModifiedDate(datetime, not null)

Comment: No, every user did not attend on every session.

Comment: Basically, we have a tool which does a OID query and I'd like to rewrite this query to SQL and finally to powershell because OID query must be launched manually which is not what we want. This is the OID if it helps:Sessions?$filter = StartDate ge datetime'2017-04-06T08:39:02' and StartDate le datetime'2018-04-06T08:39:02'&$select = StartDate,User/FullName,User/Upn&$expand = User

Comment: OK so userId is your join field

Comment: Still getting error when launched from powershell script: "Invalid object name 'Session'." I have read some articles regarding refreshing intellisense cache but I don't have access to this SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If User and Fullname are the same for both tables, you can use those to join the tables together. You can use getdate() for today, and dateadd for 1 month ago, so you don't have to keep changing your query for the date range.

```
select 
    startdate,
    fullname,
    upn
from
    sessions
    join user 
    on sessions.userid=user.id
where
    startdate between dateadd(month,-1,getdate()) and getdate()
```

Comment: No, Like I mentioned there are no same columns on both tables so Fullname is located only in USERS table. It doesn't make sense for me if there is no relation between tables, how it can deliver correct output. How USERS table knows that I want to extract only these users(fullname) which had a session on particullar date if user id or user name is not located on USERS table.

Comment: I apologize, I misread the first sentence as 'I have two tables: sessions with columns Startdate and user, and user with columns fullname and upn.'

Comment: Your join field is userId - see below

Comment: I will let you know later, but it seems that this would be a solution.

Comment: It's working, much appreciated, especially for finding userId as join item.

Answer (score 0):

Union operator will only work when the number of column and data type should be same in both the table. You can use full join or cross join to combine the data from both the tables